# Set more than one Marker into Google Maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-maps

I have a list of Countries (`latitude-longitude`) and for each country in the list set a marker in my Map. I use a `Google Maps SDK`.

When I try this only in the current location show the marker. In the other elements in the list doesn't appear the marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `GMSMarker` has a map property i.e the map inwhich it needs to be displayed.

Here is a  helpful class:

```
class MyCustomMap: GMSMapView {

var markers: [Marker]                   = [] // array of custom marker to be shown in the map
var defaultZoom: Float                  = 10 //default zoom level of the map

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    settings.rotateGestures = true
    isMyLocationEnabled = true
    settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(true)

}

func removeAllMarkers() {

    for eachMarker in markers {
        eachMarker.map = nil
    }

}

/// Sets the zoom level of the map to show all the marker at once with in the screen
func showAllMarkers(for markers: [Marker]) {

    var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
    for marker in markers {
        bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
    }
    let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 100.0)
    animate(with: update)

}

// MARK: - Private

func createMarker(with marker: Marker) {
    markers.append(marker)
    marker.map = self
}

func createMarkers(with markers: [Marker]) {

    for eachMarker in markers {
       createMarker(with: eachMarker)
    }

}
}
```

Here marker is my custom marker, which inherits `GMSMarker`

```
class Marker : GMSMarker {

 }
```

Also, if you are trying to show a marker in your current location after fetching it, make a new marker with the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` lat and longitude and add it in the map.

```
marker.map = your_mapview
```